# XCTest Array extension in swift

Tags: clang, swift, xctest

I wish to unit test my `Array` extension.

```
extension Array {
    func itemPassingTest(test: (T) -> Bool) -> T? {
        for item in self {
            if test(item) {
                return item
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

In my unit test target, I have

```
import XCTest
import JLTExample

class JLTExampleTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExtensionArray() {
        let target = [ ["a" : 1], ["a" : 2], ["a" : 3] ]
        let actual = target.itemPassingTest { $0["a"] == 2 }
        XCTAssertNotNil(actual)
    }

}
```

When building I get the error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "__TFSa15itemPassingTestU__fGSaQ__FFQSbGSqQ_", referenced from:
      __TFC17JLTExampleTests17JLTExampleTests18testExtensionArrayfS0_FT_T_ in JLTExampleTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My guess is I'm importing my extension, but I don't know how to import an extension. I was hoping that my extension would have been imported with the rest of my code in  `import JLTExample`.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175596/swift-framework-does-not-include-symbols-from-extensions-to-generic-structs#comment37316276_24175596

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an existing question, but couldn't find one. I'm guessing mine's a duplicate: both structs use generics.

Comment: @JefferyThomas yes, it turns out this is a bug with the compiler. The compiler is mangling the names of generics incorrectly. Hopefully they fix it in the next release.

Comment: Ugh, I don't think this is fixed yet...?