# How to distribute extensions of Array as a framework?

Tags: arrays, swift, compiler-errors, xcode6

Lets say I want to create extension method for Array that returns second item of the array. To be able to reuse it in several projects I want to make a framework of it and then embed it in other projects.

In framework project I have:

```
extension Array {
    public func second() -> T? {
        return self.count > 1 ? self[1] : nil
    }
}
```

I compile the framework, embed it in other project and I want to use it there as follows:

```
let twenty = [10, 20].second()
```

XCode 6.0.1 is happy with this but when I try to compile I get an error (*Undefined symbols for architecture arm64*). According to [Apple developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/983747#983747) this is a known issue. In XCode 6.1 seed 2 the IDE even stops me when I am trying to create extension with public methods on Array (probably meant as temporary safe belt).

Is there a workaround for this? Was anybody successful in making frameworks with this kind of extensions?

---

### Edit:

It may be helpful to note that if the extension method very simple like for example

```
extension Array {
    public func getTen() -> String {
        return "10"
    }
}
```

and the usage in other project is something like `let ten = [1].getTen()` everything compiles without errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Framework does not include symbols from extensions to generic structs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24175596/swift-framework-does-not-include-symbols-from-extensions-to-generic-structs)

Comment: @Martin I am not sure that this is an exact duplicate - in the linked question the problem is merely stated as bug while here I know this is a bug and and I am asking if there is a workaround. So the purpose of the question is different but I am not sure whether that is enough to differentiate from linked question. I am also stating more information here then is available in linked question - please see my edit.

Comment: I cannot see from your question that you *"know this is a bug"* so you might want to clarify that. And the other question also states explicitly that the problem occurs only for generic functions and gives a similar example of a "simple" (non-generic) extension that works as expected.

Comment: @MartinR Edited to clarify that I recognise this as a bug.